# loop to find the highest value in an array

Tags: solidity, arrays

I have made a struct which has an address called `playersAddress` and a uint called `numbers`.

I then have a fixed sized array which has in it the `playersAddress` and the numbers.

When someone calls the function `pickWinner`, the highest number in the `numbers` variable compared with the other numbers will transfer a certain amount of ether to the address in the playersAddress.

Also the numbers in the `numbers` variable are always changing value. I would like to know in this situation would the only way to find the highest number in an array would be to use a loop?  I have tried to write out a for loop in the `pickWinner` function, but it keeps coming up with an error.

```
function getPickWinner() public {

    var test = numbers;
    var largest = 0;
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        if (test[i] > largest) {
            largest = test[i];
    }
}
```

The error comes up in the `var i;` part and it says assignment necessary for type detection.

I would like to know what this means and how I could fix it? At the moment I am not worrying about gas or anything I just want to experiment a bit first. If gas is a really big issue would it be possible in this scenario to do the loop offchain but keep everything else the way it is ? How could I possibly go about doing it offchain? thank you

Answer (score 1):

This code will do what you ask.

Note the variable declarations. `var` is deprecated.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;

contract test3 {

    uint256[5] public numbers = [1, 2, 100, 4, 5];

    function getPickWinner() public view returns(uint256){
        uint256 largest = 0; 
        uint256 i;

        for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            if(numbers[i] > largest) {
                largest = numbers[i]; 
            } 
        }
        return largest;
    }
}
```

I have set the variable numbers just for testing purposes. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Use [utilities](https://github.com/Modular-Network/ethereum-libraries-array-utils#getmaxuint256-storage-public-view-returnsuint256) to solve such kinda problems. No builtin functions available.

Considering Off-chain calculations, yes it would be great if we calculate/transfer assets among users in our system. And assign only their true assets by submitting on main chain finally when they leave our system.

PS: Like Plasma MVP

Answer (score 0):

`var` is deprecated. Give your variables types. In particular, use `uint256 i` to silence this, but go ahead and give all the variables types:

```
uint256 test = numbers;
uint256 largest = 0;
uint256 i;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: If you are using `var` for a declaration of the variable i then you need to assign value to variable at the time of declaration like `var i=0`. I suggest you to use `uint` instead of `var` for i and largest variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try my utilities library https://www.npmjs.com/package/libsol
to get the greatest number from an Array of uint256s

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use local struct or data to keep largest and return. You can also return index, Easy to use more useful.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.9;
type UFixed256x18 is uint256;

contract Maths {


    function max(uint256[] calldata numbers)
        public
        pure
        returns (uint256 largest)
    {
        uint256 len = numbers.length;
        require(len > 0, "Empty numbers");
        largest = numbers[0];
        if (len == 1) {
            return largest;
        }
        for (uint256 i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            uint256 curr = numbers[i];
            if (curr > largest) {
                largest = curr;
            }
        }
    }

    function max_i(uint256[] calldata numbers)
        public
        pure
        returns (uint256 largest, uint256 index)
    {
        uint256 len = numbers.length;
        require(len > 0, "Empty numbers");
        largest = numbers[0];
        if (len == 1) {
            return (largest, 0);
        }
        for (uint256 i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            uint256 curr = numbers[i];
            if (curr > largest) {
                largest = curr;
                index = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```